# How to check if android device's firebase connection back again?

Tags: android, firebase, connection

I have an app that uses primarily MySQL database to store data and uses firebase just only to push notifications. I want my device to check the MySQL data table when the device's internet connection lost and back again. So I think a firebase connection check can help me with the device connection state. Is there any Firebase method I can use that checks reconnecting status?

Comment: Which Firebase product are you using?  The Firebase platform has over a dozen different products, and two of them are databases.

Answer (score 0):

Got this code from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('http://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com');
firebaseRef.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
    /* we're connected! */
  } else {
    /* we're disconnected! */
  }
```

});

Hope might help you!

Comment: This line `new Firebase('http://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com');` is incredibly outdated, not in the documentation you linked, and for web instead of Android. For the up to date and correct snippet, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Comment: Oh, I don't work with firebase and android. But I made a chat app with firebase 1 year ago.